# Easy.py (libsvm) crashing before creating model

Tags: python, libsvm

I've been trying to run the easy.py script provided by libsvm-3.17 however it is crashing before creating the model. It does generate the range, scale, output file and gnuplot image but not model, and I believe I do need this to classify the test data. Any input is greatly appreciated :) Thanks.

The error is :
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "tools\easy.py", line 61, in 
    c,g,rate = map(float,last_line.split())
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'[0x7FFFB2243810]'

I've tried several data sets, this error pops up everytime.

[image]

Comment: could you please provide some code?

Comment: all I did was call easy.py from cmd as in 

cmd> easy.py <train data> <test data>

Comment: then show us the code in the file easy.py? how do you expect us to debug the issue if we cannot see the code?

Comment: my apologies, thought that you knew that this is an opensource svm library.

link to easy.py https://github.com/erg/libsvm/blob/master/tools/easy.py